# Which settings daemon for numlock and repeat delay on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: keyboard, settings, session

I just switched from Ubuntu 16.04 32bits to Ubuntu 20.04 64bits, and since many things changed, I have to rethink my i3wm setup.

From the `~/.config/i3/config` file, I am starting these settings daemons:

- `/usr/libexec/gsd-xsettings`
- `/usr/libexec/gsd-keyboard`
- `/usr/libexec/gsd-a11y-settings`
- `/usr/libexec/gsd-color`
- `/usr/libexec/gsd-datetime`
- `/usr/libexec/gsd-sound`

It seems fine, except when I log in an i3 session, numlock is not On unlike when I log in an Ubuntu session. Similarly, the keyboard repeat delay is not the same, it remains the default one.

I tried starting these settings daemon from `~/.xprofile` instead, but this changes nothing.

I guess I am missing a settings daemon, but which one?

— Edit —

Seems the daemon is the good one, but it fails to start. Trying to run `gsd-keyboard` from the command line, I get an error about “DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files”.

Comment: Repeat keys can be set via System Settings -->> Universalaccess --> Repeat Keys.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7A8t.png

Comment: Yes, I know, but it does not applies when I am running i3.

Comment: you needed to call it with env variable.. I will search a link n send u in sometime..

Comment: Hey I have come across with the similar case but googling now I cant find.. but you can run this command and set the Repeat Keys Configuration.. `env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center` https://sakhnik.com/2018/08/02/i3-gnome.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the same I also tried adding `env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME`  to each settings daemons invocations. May be that's a bug If ever I figure how to solve it in the future, I will tell here

Comment: recently i encounterd the same thing but not able get that link.. its from askubuntu.com Q & A only.. the OP raised the Q n he himself answered it..

Comment: It seems to be related to DBus. I added a note on this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `unity-settings-daemon` instead of the GNOME settings daemons, solves the issue. It is not part of the default installation, so I can’t be sure it will always be available in the future.